# Samsung Moment telephone through AUX

Tags: 2.2-froyo, hardware

I have an iPhone, and while in my car, I can connect to the radio through my AUX jack and use the phone that way. The iPhone microphone picks up just fine and I hear the person through the car speakers. While I don't **think** Apple intended for it to be used this way, it works just fine.

My mom has the Samsung Moment, and when we tried that in her car, I couldn't hear her at all. Does Android disable the microphone when an aux cable is plugged into the headphone jack? If so, is there any way around it? Has anyone had success with using an Android phone in a vehicle radio like this?

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I have a Motorola Droid and I plug in a FM transmitter into the headphone jack and my mic still works (because I use this to make calls while driving).

Does the AUX cable also have a mic on it?  If so, maybe that is overriding the phone's mic input.

Comment: I do the same thing and it works fine on my Droid.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but nope. The AUX doesn't have a mic on it. It's just a standard 1/8" to 1/8" connector

Comment: Try this: plug in any set of headphones (that do not have a mic).  Call someone.  Try talking to them.  Does the mic work then?  Maybe the FM transmitter that you are using is the problem? This is the one I use: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000E43GOO/ref=oss_product

Comment: Good idea Bryan. I'll try that next time I see her. I don't have an FM transmitter though, the head unit has an AUX input jack.

Comment: @Thomas well, using headphones should either tell you one of two things: 1) Something is wrong with the AUX input jack 2) something is wrong with the headphones jack of the phone (or a software problem of the phone?)